# Count The number of child from tree table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table tilted as `tbltre`
Table Structure is like:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` longtext NOT NULL, 
`parent` int(10) unsigned default '0'
```

Content of table is like this:

```
 id  Title  parent
.....................
    1   abc    0
    2   xyz    1
    3   pqr    1
    4   uuu    2
```

Required results is -

```
 id  title  no of childs
...........................
    1   abc     3
    2   xyz     1
    3   pqr     0
    4   uuu     0
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>This should give you what you want</strike> **EDIT** It doesn't....see the last edit below:

```
select 
  parent.id, parent.title, count(child.id) 'number of children' 
from
  ttt parent left join ttt child
    on child.parent = parent.id
group by parent.id
order by parent.id;
```

Output from mysql:

```
+----+-------+--------------------+
| id | title | number of children |
+----+-------+--------------------+
|  1 | abc   |                  2 |
|  2 | xyz   |                  1 |
|  3 | pqr   |                  0 |
|  4 | uuu   |                  0 |
+----+-------+--------------------+
```

**EDIT:** At least in MySQL, the `ORDER BY` is [superfluous](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns. To avoid the overhead of sorting that GROUP BY  produces, add ORDER BY NULL

Thanks for the tip, thomasrutter!

**EDIT:** Well, thaggie pointed out that I'm suffering from a case of not carefully reading the question here. The answer above only gets children of a parent, not all descendants. As others have pointed out, if you're using Oracle you can use their [STARTS WTIH/CONNECT BY](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/oracle9i/daily/oct04.html) syntax. Otherwise [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) may be of interest.

Comment: Looks like you, MarcusQ and I got basically the same answer a few minutes apart :)  I omitted the ORDER BY because (at least in mysql AFAIK) GROUP BY implies sorting in the same way.

Comment: Heh, yeah. I guess it's a classic self-join kinda question. Thanks for the tip on GROUP BY vs ORDER BY -- the MySQL documentation agrees with you :-)

Comment: Yeah - you both got the wrong answer, check your results against what he's asking for - you're counting the children he's wanting the descendants.

Comment: @thaggie: Good point. Well, we're back to Oracle "STARTS WITH/CONNECT BY" then, I guess. There's apparently no equivalent in MySQL.

Comment: it consider only single level . what should I do if I have nth level

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.title,
  COUNT(*) AS children
FROM
  tbltree AS a
  INNER JOIN tbltree AS b ON
    b.parentid=a.id
GROUP BY
  a.id
```

This requires only one self-join, you would want to have an index on tbltree.id for the GROUP BY statement (presumably you have it as your PRIMARY), and an index on tbltree.parentid to make this join efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Oracle, I'd suggest using a CONNECT BY which would make this a simple query.

You might be able to do a group by/having as a subselect.

```
SELECT ID parent_id, TITLE, (
SELECT COUNT(ID) from tbltree group by ID having parent = parent_id) child_count
FROM tbltree;
```

This is untested, and only works for one level deep on the tree.

Comment: It looks like this is has been an enhancement request for some time for mysql

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had my coffee yet, but you might want to try something along the lines of

```
select 
    p.id, p.title, count(c.*) 
  from tbltree as c 
  left join tbltree as p 
  where p.id = c.parent 
  group by p.id
  order by p.id
```

Comment: No coffee yet here either, but that smells right.

Comment: Marked down, he wanted the descendants not the children.

Comment: @thaggie Then (if you are correct) he should have used the words "all descendants" not "children" and "childs" in the question.  SQL I can do.  Mind reading, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your prbolem... Worked for me

```
select F.id as Parent, F.Title ,Count(S.ID) as ChildCount 
from tbltree F 
left outer join tbltree S on F.id = S.Parent 
Group BY F.id ,F.Title
```

Comment: why group by the title too? it hurts.